# find_first_of in c++ gives different values

Tags: c++

In the code below, I don't understand why b is false.

```
string s = "--p--";
cout << s.find_first_of("p") << endl; //prints 2
bool b = s.find_first_of("p")>-1;
cout << b << endl;  //prints 0 (why?)
```

Comment: Comparing signed and unsigned integers isn't a good idea. Did you mean to compare against `std::string::npos` instead? Which standard library reference are you using?

Comment: @Nicky if you are comparing Double d & double d both are different same way here in signed integer

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are right. However this is just a small part of the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`s.find_first_of("p")` returns a `size_t` which is an `unsigned` type.

The `>` operator will convert `-1` to an unsigned type before `s.find_first_of("p")>-1;` is evaluated. That's how C++ works: if an operator that takes two arguments encounters a `signed` and an `unsigned` type as those arguments, then the `signed` one gets converted to an `unsigned` one.

`-1` when converted to an unsigned type will be a large positive number. (In fact, it will *wrap around* to the largest value of `size_t`.)

So your comparison evaluates to `false`.

To check if a character is not in a string, use `b = s.find_first_of("p") != string::npos;`

Comment: I see. Do you have a suggestion on how to approach this problem? I need to return the position of 'p' (2 in this case) and I need to check if the string actually contains the character 'p'

Comment: I've now taken the time to read the question, and have put in the correct test ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`std::string::find_first_of()` return value is of type `size_t`, and that's typedef for some unsigned type. In order to compare to integer{-1}, compiler should yield a common type. According to the standard *usual arithmetic conversions*:

> If the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the
>   rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
>   the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

That means, something like that happens:

```
bool b = s.find_first_of("p")>static_cast<unsigned>(-1);
```

You could compile following simple program to observe the behavior.

```
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
  int i = -1;
  std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(i);
}
```